# Why express4 with angularjs rewrite the url on browser?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I made a demo to integrate Express 4 with AngularJS.

It works fine, that

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

shows the welcome page in ng-view of index, and

```
http://localhost:3000/#/users
```

show the users page in ng-view.

But when visit

```
http://localhost:3000/#/users
```

after the page is loaded, the url on the browser change to

```
http://localhost:3000/users
```

And this is not the right path.

I really have no idea why?

Anyway to make it not change?

Anybody know?

Router in app.js:

var web = require('./routes/web');
    app.use('/', web);

```
....

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    res.sendfile('web/index.html');
});
```

AngularJS app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'shopControllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/views/tpl/welcome.html',
                controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'})
            .when('/users', {
                templateUrl: '/views/tpl/users.html',
                controller: 'UserListCtrl'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

AngularJS controller：

```
var shopControllers = angular.module('shopControllers', []);

shopControllers.controller('WelcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.username = 'Conan_Z';
    }]);

shopControllers.controller('UserListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('service/user/get.json?shopVipId=2').success(function(data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        });

        $scope.orderProp = 'age';
    }]);
```

AngularJS index.html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class=".col-lg-12">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line below,
this basically removes the # for html5 supported web browsers, it's not a bad thing, but it's better to have the # at the moment for compatibility issues.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: Hi z.a, I'm new to Stackoverflow, this is my first ask. How to give you credit? Click the up button?

Comment: also, you can put a check mark right below the up button, as its the correct answer.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing related to express.

This is due to angular js location provider is using history API.

In your route remove

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This will solve your problem.